# Android Studio 3.3 showing textview text in different language in layout preview

Tags: android-studio

I had a project working completely fine few days ago, but when I opened it today, it shows all the text of the layout in some different language.

I don't have any translations files for strings.xml and have used only English language throughout the app for text but still it shows text in some different language.

See the below screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

In the above screenshot you can see that the attribute text of the selected field shows **"Select Class"** as the value of the text but in the preview it shows in some weird language.

I also checked, I don't have any plugins related to translation installed in Android Studio.
Also this issue is with all the layouts in the project.

I tried clean/rebuild but still has the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

In Design Preview, click on Locale drop down. Next, You'll have translation Editor.
Here, you can select **Untranslatable** with file name. It indicates that you do not want the text in this row to be translated. [image: Reference Screenshot]

Comment: I have read your question completely. Could you please check, if there is any other locale installed in your android studio by clicking globe icon (check in above SS)

Comment: There are no other locales available

Comment: Then, you should give Untranslatable(checkboxes) thing a try.

Comment: Can you find something in Translation field below?

Comment: I only have a single strings.xml file and I am not doing any kind of translation in my app

Comment: Then, this could be Android studio bug, you can report it here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=issues%2F